# How to implement lazy image load

Tags: sxa

I am trying to implement lazy image loading functionality for the `img` element. Is there any way to implement lazy image loading functionality in SXA while loading images on the page?

Comment: This is not related to Sitecore. Should be closed and asked elsewhere

Comment: I agree that lazy loading of images is not Sitecore related but SXA, in fact, can help achieve this. That's why I think this question makes sense here.

Comment: You are correct @DawidRutkowski. I have retracted my vote

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do it! I will skip the part of how lazy loading should work, as there are plenty of blog posts about it like:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/
- https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/

But here is one thing SXA can help with. Rendering Variants supports tokens inside of data attributes. Let's imagine that you have a few pages and each of those pages has an *Image* field of type `Image`. You want to display them using Page List and have all those images lazy loaded. In such case your [rendering variant](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/create_a_rendering_variant) can look like this:

[image]

The `$(Image)` token will check if *Image* is an `ImageField` and contains media and if yes it will render a link to that media item like this:

[image]

Next, you'll need some JavaScript logic to lazy load those images and it's done!

Comment: Thanks for the information David. In the above example instead of Div variant section can I use field type to render image?

Comment: What do you mean by "use field type to render image"?

Comment: It means, when we are creating Rendering items then we are getting options to create Section/Date/Field/Query/.. When Field item created then we can mentioned field name from Template which holds the image.

Comment: What I hear is that you are asking about using data attribute tokens inside of other variant items like Field, Date or any other. If that was the question then yes, you can use in all variant items which has Data Attribute field. 
There is just one issue with HTML Tag variant item - data attribute tokens are not fully working there. It's already fixed in 1.7.

Comment: Ok. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: for the javascript logic you can use this one. I have tested it. http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage

Comment: @DawidRutkowski thank you we implemented it like this but currently we are stuck at the point to render the alt text on the lazy image. The alt text belongs to the Images Media item. If we use a pass trough filed on the image to get the alt tag I have no idea how to get the media url on the img-src property because now we have the media item and not the image. Any idea?